# Como meter una consulta sql en java, sustituyendo codigo duro de un map?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Espero y se encuentren bien, tengo un problema, lo que necesito es sustituir código duro de un mapa java, por los resultados que me regresa una consulta sql, el código duro es este:

```
{
        this.correspondencia=new HashMap<String, String>();
        correspondencia.put("A","101");
        correspondencia.put("B","102");
        correspondencia.put("B1","102");
        correspondencia.put("B2","102");
        correspondencia.put("B3","102");
        correspondencia.put("B4","102");
        correspondencia.put("BPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("C","102");
        correspondencia.put("DF","102");
        correspondencia.put("EFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("EXF","102");
        correspondencia.put("GPF","102");
        correspondencia.put("MB","102");
        correspondencia.put("MFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("P","102");
        correspondencia.put("PPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("PV","102");
        correspondencia.put("TF","102");
        correspondencia.put("UHN","102");
        correspondencia.put("B","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-1","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-2","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-3","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-4","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-5","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-6","103");
        correspondencia.put("DM","103");
        correspondencia.put("E","103");
        correspondencia.put("E1","103");
        correspondencia.put("E2","103");
        correspondencia.put("EC","103");
        correspondencia.put("EXM","103");
        correspondencia.put("IF","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM1","103");
        correspondencia.put("DNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC2","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC3","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC4","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC5","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC6","104");
        correspondencia.put("NCC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("B","105");
        correspondencia.put("EX","105");
        correspondencia.put("F","107");
        correspondencia.put("GB","108");

    }


    private double calculaInversion(String nb_serie,List<VivVAACInversion> catalogoInversion) {
        String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);
        double id=0;

        for (VivVAACInversion vivVAACInversion : catalogoInversion) {
            if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(vivVAACInversion.getNombreClave())){
                id=vivVAACInversion.getIdInversion();
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Y esta es mi consulta SQL:

```
SELECT
    tviv055_intiserie.nb_serie,
    tviv053_inversion.nb_clave
FROM
    ( tviv056_relserie
    INNER JOIN tviv055_intiserie ON tviv056_relserie.cd_serie = tviv055_intiserie.cd_serie )
    INNER JOIN tviv053_inversion ON tviv056_relserie.cd_inversion = tviv053_inversion.cd_inversion
```

Tengo de ejemplo unos código que mas o menos cumplen con lo que necesito:

```
public Map<String, String[]> getProductos() {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        try {
                if (conn != null) { //verifico que mi conexión existe
                        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS";
                        Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
                        rs = stmt0.executeQuery(sql);
                        while ( rs.next() ) {
                                String arreglo[] = {rs.getString("SKU"),  rs.getString("PRECIO"), rs.getString("IMPUESTO")};
                                map.put(rs.getString("UPC"), arreglo);

                        }
                }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.info( ".: SQL exception:. " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
        }
}
```

Nota: Ya modifiqué el código a como lo necesito, ya todo completo quedo de la siguiente manera:

Asi quedo el codigo final:

```
 private Map<String, String> correspondencia;

    {
        this.correspondencia=new HashMap<String, String>();
        //Se reemplaza código duro por dinámico.
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        Map<String, String[]>map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        try {
            if(conn !=null) {
                String sql = "SELECT\r\n" + 
                        "    tviv055_intiserie.nb_serie,\r\n" + 
                        "    tviv053_inversion.nb_clave\r\n" + 
                        "FROM\r\n" + 
                        "    ( tviv056_relserie\r\n" + 
                        "    INNER JOIN tviv055_intiserie ON tviv056_relserie.cd_serie = tviv055_intiserie.cd_serie )\r\n" + 
                        "    INNER JOIN tviv053_inversion ON tviv056_relserie.cd_inversion = tviv053_inversion.cd_inversion";
                Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //Se llena el map con el resultado de la consulta.
                    correspondencia.put(rs.getString("NB_SERIE"), rs.getString("NB_CLAVE"));
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println( ".: SQL exception:. " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }


    private double calculaInversion(String nb_serie,List<VivVAACInversion> catalogoInversion) {
         String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);
         double id=0;

         for (VivVAACInversion vivVAACInversion : catalogoInversion) {
              if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(vivVAACInversion.getNombreClave())){
                   id=vivVAACInversion.getIdInversion();
              }
         }
         return id;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si comento el `this` ocurre esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prácticamente ya probaría si todo el código funcionaria, espero y me ayudar con lo ultimo, el que me ayudo a adaptar el código fue el usuario **J.Castro**

Saludos y quedo al pendiente. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adaptando un poco tu código quedaría algo así:

```
private static Map<String, String> correspondencia;

public static void correspondencia(){


    correspondencia=new HashMap<>();
    //Se reemplaza código duro por dinámico.
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        if(conn !=null) {
            String sql = "SELECT\r\n" + 
                    "    tviv055_intiserie.nb_serie,\r\n" + 
                    "    tviv053_inversion.nb_clave\r\n" + 
                    "FROM\r\n" + 
                    "    ( tviv056_relserie\r\n" + 
                    "    INNER JOIN tviv055_intiserie ON tviv056_relserie.cd_serie = tviv055_intiserie.cd_serie )\r\n" + 
                    "    INNER JOIN tviv053_inversion ON tviv056_relserie.cd_inversion = tviv053_inversion.cd_inversion";
            Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
            while (rs.next()) {
                //Se llena el map con el resultado de la consulta.
                correspondencia.put(rs.getString("NB_SERIE"), rs.getString("NB_CLAVE"));
            }
        }
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println( "SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());  
    }

}

private double calculaInversion(String nb_serie,List<VivVAACInversion> catalogoInversion) {
    String clave=this.correspondencia.get(nb_serie);
    double id=0;

    for (VivVAACInversion vivVAACInversion : catalogoInversion) {
        if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(vivVAACInversion.getNombreClave())){
            id=vivVAACInversion.getIdInversion();
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

Se reemplaza el llenado estático por el dinámico que se trae de `BD`.

Comment: Hola, ya volvi a editar mi pregunta con el codigo ya implementado en el eclipse, solo que me marca un error en el "log", practicamente eso me impide a correr la aplicacion, espero y puedas ayudarme en esta, ya que esto es por parte del trabajo. te mando un cordial saludo amigo, o igual decirme que puede ser y ya aqui lo corrijo  :)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no tienes inicializado la variable log lo que puedes hacer es omitiendo esa linea, edito la respuesta y pruebas!!

Comment: Esa parte ya quedó, por ejemplo en el return del que esta dentro del catch, como quien dice, ya no iria verdad?, ya que a lo que entiendo no estoy declarándolo en si en un metodo sino por medio de la variable "correspondencia", ya que me está saliendo un error de "Void methods cannot return a value" y cuando se lo quito todo el codigo dentro del try lo marca en amarillo :(

Comment: Así es el `return` ya no iría, ya que todo el código esta en un método `void`, si te sirvio mi respuesta marcala como aceptada.

Comment: Perfecto, volvi a editar el codigo en su etapa final, lo que me preocupa es el por que se marcan en amarillo "Que las variables locales ya no se estan usando", pongo el codigo.

Comment: Pasa eso, cuando quito el "return" :(

Comment: Edite la respuesta adaptandolo a tu código final!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, solo un comentario el "this" igual como tal, ya no iria por ejm eso " this.correspondencia=new HashMap<String, String>(); y al error a lo que entiendo "Cannot use this in a static context" que vendria siendo que no se puede llamar a un metodo estatico con el this, eso como lo podria sustituir? ya que pasa lo mismo se vuelve a marcar en amarillo :(

Comment: Anexé dos imagenes del codigo desde el eclipse, para ser un poco mas especifico, y me de a entender :)

Comment: el método correspondencia ya no lo usarías, ya que todo estaría en tu variable global correspondecia y como dices una variable o método no lo puedes invocar con this [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315488/this-cannot-use-this-in-static-context) ya edite mi respuesta espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, y por ejemplo las advertencias que se generan, asi como la imagen que puse en mi respuesta no afectaría el funcionamiento del codigo??

Comment: No solo son warnings cuando afecta el código es cuando son rojos!! Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada

Comment: Ya marqué la respuesta como aceptada, de verdad de agradezco por ayudarme con esto, para mañana probaré el codigo y ya espero que todo salga bien, sino, por aqui volvere a escribirles, de antemano te mando un cordial saludo.